# Web Page zooms when rotating iPhone 5

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

This happens only on an iPhone 5, not an iPhone 6.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open http://beta.jigsaw.com in portrait mode.
2. Select History from the top menu.
3. Rotate the phone to landscape mode.

At this point, the phone is no longer in the history section and the interface is actually zoomed in a little. Is there a way to prevent that without resorting to...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css property to your body:

`-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;`

Also you should add `width=device-width` to your viewport metatag (this doesn't disable the possibility to zoom to users).